# Python code to GET (not set) the current desktop wallpaper image

Tags: unity, python, themes, desktop-background, gtk3

Like the title says, I'd like to slurp in the entire 1920x1080 background wallpaper image into a readable object **regardless of what windows, panels, launchers, etc. may currently be on top of it**.

Python, because I like it, but I'll take what I can get. I can do C/C++. I'd rather not do Java. Please, not java. This is a small utility, not a weapons-grade application.

Why, you ask?

I want to look at a couple 100 or so random pixels from the image, try to find a common colour, then manipulate the current gtk3 theme's CSS file to change @dark_bg_color to my calculated colour, and then, *somehow*, reload the theme.

The final result will be that when the wallpaper changes, windows' title bar colours will change to "match".

I'm pretty sure I can do everything except step 1... getting the current wallpaper into a readable object. There are plenty of tutorials on how to change/set the wallpaper, but not much on getting it.

Whoa, you say! You don't KNOW what your desktop wallpaper is? No. I use **variety** and it's always downloading new wallpapers AND using my personal collection, randomly changing it every 10 minutes or so.

Comment: If your problem has been solved, mark the answer as accepted. Please do not add "solved", etc. to the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import random
from PIL import Image
from gi.repository import Gio

def get_wallpaper_uri():
    settings = Gio.Settings.new("org.gnome.desktop.background")
    uri = settings.get_string("picture-uri")
    return uri

def uri_to_path(uri):
    return uri.lstrip("file:")

def get_random_coordinates(x_max, y_max, num):
    x_values = random.sample(range(x_max), num)
    y_values = random.sample(range(y_max), num)
    return zip(x_values, y_values)

def main():
    uri = get_wallpaper_uri()
    path = uri_to_path(uri)
    image = Image.open(path)
    width, height = image.size
    coordinates = get_random_coordinates(width, height, 10)
    pixels = image.load()
    for coordinate in coordinates:
        pixel_value = pixels[coordinate]
        print(pixel_value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: And more! Lovely code, thank-you.

Comment: @NickChackowsky If this answer solved your issue, please accept it as an answer by following the instructions here http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Timo above described the way of getting it in GNOME and Unity, here is how in Xfce.

```py
import subprocess

xfce_wall_cmd = subprocess.Popen('xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitor0/workspace0/last-image', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

xfce_wall, xfce_wall_errs = xfce_wall_cmd.communicate()

xfce_wall = xfce_wall.decode('utf-8').replace('\n', '')

print(xfce_wall)
```